# How to add targets to event rule in AWS CDK java?

Tags: java, aws-cdk

I have migrated from initial version of cdk to latest version. As a lot has changed, I had to change a lot of my code. I had an event rule which trigger lambda on a specific schedule. In older version, I could add lambda as a target with a json input template.

How do you do that with latest versions. I am developing in Java

```java
Function lambdaFunction = new Function(this, functionName + "lambda", FunctionProps.builder()
    .handler(functionName + ".handler")
    .functionName(functionName + "-" + parameter.getValueAsString())
    .runtime(Runtime.NODEJS_8_10)
    .code(Code.bucket(lambdaS3Bucket, collectPaymentsS3BucketKey.getValueAsString()))
    .role(lambdaExecutionRole)
    .timeout(Duration.seconds(60))
    .environment(environmentMap)
    .build());
 Rule cloudwatchRule = new Rule(this, "id", RuleProps.builder()
    .description("this triggers to collect installment payments scheduled everyday")
    .ruleName("smartpay-schedule-payments" + "-" + parameter.getValueAsString())
    .schedule(Schedule.expression("0/5 * * * ? *"))
    .build());
```

I am trying this 
        `cloudwatchRule.addTarget(lambdaFunction);`

but it does not work. How do you create a IRuleTarget object in aws cdk java.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I was able to figure out after I added dependency for events-targets

```
cloudwatchRule.addTarget(new LambdaFunction(lambdaFunction, LambdaFunctionProps.builder()
            .event(RuleTargetInput.fromText("{\"installmentStatus\" : \"SCHEDULED\" }"))
            .build()));
```